# python bottle boddle - patch(... side-effect="Exception) not working. What am I doing wrong

Tags: python, python-requests, mocking, bottle

With: Python 3.7, Bottle, Boddle, Requests

I have one module to be tested (server), and a second module with the test code (test).

The tested code (server.py):

```html
@bt_app.post("/")
def server_post():
    try:
        bt.request.forms.get("msg", None)
    except bt.BottleException:
        print("BottleException")
```

Testing code (test.py):

```html
def test_test():
    with boddle(), \
         patch(
             "server.bt.request.forms.get",
             side_effect=server.bt.BottleException,
              ), \
         pytest.raises(server.bt.BottleException):
                server.server_post()
```

I first run 'server', which successfully sets up a server.

I then run 'test', which successfully accesses and tests the server.

I expect the test to raise "BottleException" and PASS, but it does not.  It DOES properly fail stating: "Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'bottle.BottleException'>"

Can anyone give me a pointer of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without the alias.

```
...
with pytest.raises(bottle.BottleException):
...
```

Comment: Great suggestion, and it had some effect.  I went slightly further, and used 'from bottle import Bottle, request, BottleException'  I revised server to conform.  1. I successfully run server.  2. When I run test_server, I properly raises an exception in 'request.bt.forms.get' (verified by print statements).  But still gives an error "Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'bottle.BottleException'>"   Now I'm completely baffled

Comment: SOLVED!!  I realized that, because I'm handling the exception, no exception is raised by the server module.  Instead, I can sense the exception by the returned data in the 'except' clause.  But it was your suggestion which solved the core problem.  Thank you.